# is there any clue this implementation represent which activation function

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Here is code :

```
def _hard_sigmoid(x):
    return tf.clip_by_value(tf.rint((x*0.2)/0.5),tf.rint(0.0),tf.rint(1.0))

def binary_tanh(x): # activation binarization to 1 and 0
    a = (_hard_sigmoid(x)/0.5)*0.2
    b = tf.clip_by_value(x, 0, 1)
    return K.stop_gradient(a-b)+b
```

binary_tanh(x)  # we are calling this function

This related to squeezedet CNN network activation function for each layer.

**My question**

1. Which activation function it represents.
2. What value I can set for my demo application. Like here they are dividing with some value and multiply by some value.

Comment: `1. What activation it represents?` -  It represents the activation that the function ` _hard_sigmoid()` defines. `2. What value I can set for my demo application. Like here they are dividing with some value and multiply by some value.` - Not clear what you're asking. What value are  you talking about?

Comment: Value means they are dividing with 0.5 and multiply with 0.2, so why with this hard coded value only .and hard sigmoid has implementation like  x = (x * slope) + shift.but it does not looks they have implemented like this.